# How to map/classify dates in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that shows the announcement dates of quarter financials for companies. The problem is that the data is mapped/classified wrongly. MSFT and TSLA are examples of these distorted rows. As you can see, the rows have missing data that are skipped thus being mapped to earlier dates(MSFT). Whereas in TSLA the first few columns are duplicates of the first row.

APPL and FACE is a correct example, where the column dat3 and the row date is similar to one another.

```
Company_Name  Q1 2012  Q2 2012 Q3 2012 ..... Q4 2019
APPL  15022012 16052012 20082012 13112012 ........ 12122019 
FACE  23022012 12052012 22082012 13112012 ........ 20122019 
MSFT  22022019 11052019 24082019 11112019
TSLA  15022012 15022012 15022012 13112012 ........ 20122019
```

I plan to map/classify the dates so that each column will have the appropriate dates. i.e.

```
Q1 --> 010220XX - 010520XX
Q2 --> 010520XX - 010820XX
Q3 --> 010820XX - 011120XX
Q4 --> 011120XX - 010220(XX+1)
```

Thank you very much for your help.

The picture shows the raw csv data. The columns are quarters of each year and the dates on the cells correspond to the announcement dates of the company's financial in that quarter
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUlWy.png

Comment: How do you get your data? It is an csv file? Can you share the format?

Comment: Yes it is a csv file i'll add a screenshot. Can you clarify on what u mean by format?

Answer (score -1):

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("t.csv", index_col=None)

df_transpose = df.T
df_transpose = df_transpose[1:]
df_transpose

idx = df_transpose.index.values
idx = [i.split('20')[0] for i in idx]
idx

df_transpose['index'] = idx
df2 = df_transpose.set_index('index')
df2

df3 = tuple(df2.groupby('index')) 

df_final = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df3:
    p = i[1][0:1]
    q = i[1][1:2]
    row = pd.concat([p, q], axis=1, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
    df_final = df_final.append(row)

df_final
```

**Image**
[image: importation & upload file]
[image: transpose dataframe]
[image: append dataframe]

Comment: Please do NOT insert code screenshots into questions or answers. They are useless because they cannot be copied or edited.

Comment: understanding first and after ctrl + C ctrl + V. But I understood; thanks

Comment: @ArmelDrey [Why do we hate screenshots so much?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/) Screenshots are 0. not copy-pasteable. 1. not searchable. 2. not readable by people using screen readers 3. not legible when the entire screenshot is compressed into a third of the width of my screen by my browser.

Comment: You should post your code [_as formatted text_](/help/formatting). SO includes a code highlighter that will highlight any code you put in code fences.

Comment: Also, while code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Okey  **@Pranav Hosangadi**, **@DYZ**  thank you all, I understood. 
I just added the code shown in the image.